# Acumatica Mobile Site Map for 2018 R2

Tags: acumatica

I've been trying to find the Mobile Site Map for **2018 R2**.  I know that it was originally in the `\App_Data\Mobile` for **R1**, but they must of moved it in **R2**.  Can some please explain where the Mobile Site Map is now for your local instance of Acumatica?

Comment: On 2018R2 you can modify the sitemap through the Customization Project editor tool. See more details on how to change the sitemap on 2018R2 version here: https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c7e5bca7-aebc-4c40-878e-94535fa91c9e    is there any reason besides modifying the sitemap that you would need to locate the sitemap file on local instance?

Comment: No I was just stating that it was on my local mechanic and not on the cloud.  because in R1 you had to add the files in the mobile app.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 2018 R2, the mobile site map and page definitions are stored in the database.  You can extract them from the database with a simple script using SSMS on your local development instance.  My database, for example, is called Sandbox.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1000) [MobileSiteMap].[CompanyID]
      ,[MobileSiteMap].[ScreenID]
      ,[SiteMap].[Title]
      ,[Type]
      ,char(13) + ltrim([MobileSiteMap].[Script]) + char(13)
  FROM [Sandbox].[dbo].[MobileSiteMap]
  Left Join [SiteMap] On [SiteMap].[ScreenID] = [MobileSiteMap].[ScreenID]
```

Be advised that the old XML method of extending screens to mobile has been replaced by Acumatica's new MSDL markup, in JSON format.  Acumatica just gave a T400 and T410 class on mobile at Acumatica Summit 2019 as part of the Web Services class.  The pdf guides should be available soon if not already, but at last check the course was not on Open University yet.  As a fairly new developer on the Acumatica Framework, I struggled with the XML syntax, but the MSDL syntax seems to be MUCH easier to understand after a few samples from the training course.

As cbetabeta noted, you do your customizations on 2018 R2 in the Customization Project on a new section called "Mobile Application".  Anything you add here will show up in your SQL extract, which you can copy to Notepad++ to "copycat" program existing screen layouts/actions into your own screens while you learn MSDL.